# What should I put in the imageUpload of the redactor Parameter?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, wysiwyg, redactor

I currently use vue for frontend and django for backend.
I'm using the editor of the redactor in the frontend vue, but I don't know what to put in the imageUpload.
Should I put backend's API? This is my current code.

```
  configOptions = {
    buttons: ['format', 'bold', 'italic', 'lists', 'link', 'image', 'file'],
    plugins: ['imagemanager', 'filemanager']
    imageUpload:
      'http://backend-url/image/',
    imageData: {
      id: 10,
      elements: '#my-input, #my-form'
    }
  }
```

Comment: See this link on how to work with images and redactor https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/how-to/upload-images/

Answer (score 1):

You can use imageUpload to upload an image inline with the text. To add an image, you can add a function to imageUpload that submits the image to your database or vuex store. For example;

```
imageUpload: (data, files, e, upload) => {
    // commit to your vuex store, or do a post request to your API url.                  
},
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You have been very helpful to me! I have one more question. I checked the imageUpload function for a response, but if I add a picture, I can't see the picture inside the editor. What should I do with this?

Comment: And can you tell me where I can see information about imageManger of vue redactor?

Comment: @Rebbeca What do you mean with "I can't see the picture inside the editor"? You don't get a response?

Comment: There was a response, but the photo was not displayed. But this was a bug that was caused by not receiving url from the server. Thank you!
Does the redactor always have to send pictures to the server when uploading them? Can't I send all the pictures to the server at once when I finished writing a post?